# Add a new entity in json

Tags: c#, json

I am using c#(but this is not so relevant with my question) to read some JSON records.

I get movie-records like:

```
{
   "items": [   
    { "key": "3", "data": {"idx": "1", "movie-title": "Hangover 2", "duration": "102", "imdb_link": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1411697/"}}
]}
```

and therefore I use the following JSON scheme that describes the above records and ***works flawlessly:***

```
{
  "fields": [
    { "name": "idx", "type": "Edm.Int32" },
    { "name": "movie-title", "type": "Edm.String" },
    { "name": "duration", "type": "Edm.Int32" },
    { "name": "imdb_link", "type": "Edm.String" },
  ]
}
```

However, the API I use is changed, and I will get the creators of the movies as well. An example of the new data record is shown below:

```
{
   "items": [   
    { "key": "3", "data": {"idx": "1", "movie-title": "Hangover 2", "duration": "102", "imdb_link": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1411697/", "creators": {"directors": ["Todd Phillips"]}}}
]}
```

I have tried to edit the scheme as below, but the records cannot be parsed:

```
{
  "fields": [
    { "name": "idx", "type": "Edm.Int32" },
    { "name": "movie-title", "type": "Edm.String" },
    { "name": "duration", "type": "Edm.Int32" },
    { "name": "imdb_link", "type": "Edm.String" },
    {"name":"creators", "type": { "name": "directors", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)" }}
  ]
}
```

How is it possible to edit my json scheme to include this new change as well?

Comment: Your new JSON string appears to be valid. What's the error message?